# Connecting to RDS from AWS Pipeline EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am having a lot of trouble with this and can't find any solution online that will fix my issue.

The goal is to setup an AWS Pipeline to take CSV data from an S3 bucket and put it into an RDS instance. I have two activies inside of my pipeline: create a table if it doesn't exist, and copy the data to the table. However, the pipeline always fails after it tries to create the table in the RDS instance because it can't connect to it. Here is the error:

```
errorId: ActivityFailed:NullPointerException
amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.SqlActivity.runActivity(SqlActivity.java:71) at amazonaws.datapipeline.objects.AbstractActivity.run(AbstractActivity.java:16) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeRemoteRunner(TaskPoller.java:136) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller.executeTask(TaskPoller.java:105) at amazonaws.datapipeline.taskrunner.TaskPoller$1.run(TaskPoller.java:81) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.executeWork(PollWorker.java:76) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.poller.PollWorker.run(PollWorker.java:53) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. at private.com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Unknown Source) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:192) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:177) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getRdsDatabaseConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:161) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:73) at amazonaws.datapipeline.activity.SqlActivity.runActivity(SqlActivity.java:63) ... 7 more Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:917) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885) at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2330) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806) at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527) at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410) at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328) at private.com.amazonaws.services.datapipeline.database.DriverShim.connect(DriverShim.java:26) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571) at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.connect(ConnectionFactory.java:203) at amazonaws.datapipeline.database.ConnectionFactory.getConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:187) ... 11 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getServerCharset(ConnectionImpl.java:2997) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendConnectionAttributes(MysqlIO.java:1936) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1865) at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1228) at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253) at com.mysql.jdbc.Co
```

One thing to note is that the pipeline is setup in us-east-1, but I have the RDS and EC2 going into us-east-2. I thought I set it up correctly though.

The ec2 instance that is created by the pipeline is set to go into the same subnet as the rds instance. The rds instance has a security group that allows all incoming traffic from the security group of the ec2 instance. The ec2 instance is created with a security group that allows all outgoing traffic. I also made sure the Ec2 instance that is created ends up in the same region as the rds.

It doesn't make much sense to me that this doesn't work because I can manually create an ec2 instance with the same security & subnet settings and connect to the database using `telnet <rds endpoint> 3306`.

I do not have much experience with AWS so any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: RDS instance created by pipeline or it always run?

Comment: Always run, sorry.

Comment: Sorry for the long answer. In my case, I've set up a pipeline and connect to the outside the VPC. I've used that solution: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/data-pipeline-connect-ec2-vpc/

It's my guess, but probably in your case automatically created ec2 instance can't resolve DNS name or IP address for RDS instance. Could you print more details about the low-level network error under that exception?

Comment: Updated with the full stack trace. I'll follow that solution to see if it works for me.

Comment: Just an update, I ended up redoing everything so that it was all in the same Region and was able to get it to work. I think the issue was some sort of networking issue within AWS. That's a problem for the future... I just want to test if a pipeline will solve my problem.